# Docker exec OF not working from outside the container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-machine, openfoam

I've built a docker image where there's OpenFoam install inside. When I run decomposePar -case case0 or any OF command inside the image works properyly.
However, when I try to run it from outside (e.g. docker exec -it  decomposePar -case case0) says "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "decomposePar": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown".
I've checked the $PATH and it's build correctly.
¿What am I doing wrong?

**More info:**
I test to run other programs like python, "docker exec -it brave_noether python3 script.py", and works just fine. But, when it arrives to the OF command crashes like: "sh: 1: decomposePar: not found"

Cheers.

**Update**

$PATH ->  usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/bin:/data/foam-v2212/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin:/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/site/2212/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin:/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin:/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/bin:/usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/wmake:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

And for example decomposePar is in -> /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2212/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/decomposePar

**Install OF via dockerFile:**

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | sudo bash ;
apt-get install -y openfoam-default ;
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/bash foam ;
echo "foam ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN echo "source /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam/etc/bashrc" >> ~foam/.bashrc ;
echo "export OMPI_MCA_btl_vader_single_copy_mechanism=none" >> ~foam/.bashrc

RUN sed -i '/export WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR=/cexport WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR="/data/foam-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION"' /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam/etc/bashrc

**More updates**
I've reached a further troubleshooting. It seems to not set environment variables properly. You have to set them also when running docker exec, like:
docker exec brave_noether bash -c 'export env_vars; decomposePar ...'

Now the problem is that OF doesn't recognize controlDict in spite of located correctly.

**Solution**

If someone encounters the very same situation. Just follow the next command:

docker exec <container_name/id> bash -c 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH; source /PATH/TO/OF/etc/bashrc; decomposePar -case /PATH/TO/CASE'

Note that environment variables have to be set to the content inside the container. Also, that bash is in my case, you have to see it in docker ps -a command.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Do you install this command somewhere in the standard `$PATH`?  Can you run this command without the `docker exec` debugging tool?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is very likely that the OpenFOAM environment is not being properly set before launching the command. I would recommend using one of the official docker images
https://hub.docker.com/r/opencfd

If you want insight into how these are being built, the source repo is available here:
https://develop.openfoam.com/packaging/containers/-/blob/main/openfoam-docker